# MDX // Filter DESCANDANTS on Columns including ALL

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to get a set of certain members from a hierarchy including the ALL-Member.

```
SELECT 
    [Measures].[Distinct Count SKU]
ON 0,
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Filter Place].[Location].[All],, SELF_AND_AFTER    
        )
ON 1
FROM 
    [STOCK]
```

I do get the All-Member from this expression, however it contains locations I would like to have filtered out.

This is what I get:
[image]

This is what I want to get:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to use the descendants function, insteed use the [ALL] level. in a simple set.

```
SELECT     [Measures].[Distinct Count SKU] ON 0,
{
[Filter Place].[Location].[All],
[Filter Place].[Location].[Berlin],
[Filter Place].[Location].[London],
[Filter Place].[Location].[Paris]
} ON 1
FROM [STOCK]
```